# Truncating netCDF

Tags: netcdf, truncation, nco, cdo-climate

I have a netCDF file of monthly surface air temperature from 1850-2005. How can I truncate the file in unix so that the new file has a time dimension from 1855 - 2005? And vice versa, truncating the file so that it is instead for 1850-2000?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [NCO](http://nco.sf.net)

```
ncks -d time,60, in.nc  1855-2005.nc
ncks -d time,,-60 in.nc 1850-2000.nc
```

See [documentation](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#hyp)

Answer (score 4):

CDO allows you use a direct date format if you prefer:

```
cdo seldate,date1,date2 in.nc out.nc
```

so the equivalent to Charlie's nco commands would be

```
cdo seldate,18550101,20051231 in.nc 1855-2005.nc
cdo seldate,18500101,20001231 in.nc 1850-2000.nc
```

(assuming you want to include the years specified in the year range).